# type of undefined not working for document.getelementbyId

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Using a timer to check if an object is populated...however if its not defined I just want to skip that code...but I cant seem to get it...

so I have

```
 if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName('ad-area') !== undefined)
      {
    let one = document.getElementsByClassName('ad-area')[i].children[0].href;
}
```

but its failing with

```
document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined
```

I know this is the line as I have added console logs to see where its failing

have tried

```
if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName('ad-area') !== object)
```

any help please?

Comment: FYI `querySelector` returns a single element of `null` which probably fits your case better... `const one = document.querySelector('.ad-area')?.children[0].href`

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` will return an array-like object (HTMLCollection), which can either be empty (non found) or will contain 1 or more elements found, so check for the length:

`if ( document.getElementsByClassName('ad-area').length > 0 )`

References: [getElementsByClassName @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)